NGINX Can't access website via domain only localhost
I can acceess my nginx website via localhost:8082 but can't access it with usage of webite/server/ domain name which is: purple.com or purple.com:8082 error message: The site can't be reached purple.com took too long to respond.
What can I do to access my local website via url addressLpurple.com not localhost:8082?
I opened both ports 8082,8083 in windows firewall in inbounds and outbound rules.
I've added 127.0.0.1 purple.com to etc/hosts file on windows.
I've run dnsflush command
I've run Test-NetConnection -ComputerName purple.com -Port 8082 and gets warning: TCP connect to (ip address of WSL Machine: 8082) failed.
I'm using WSL installed on windows. My website file configuration is next:
`server {
            underscores_in_headers on;

            listen 8083 ssl;

            proxy_buffering off;

            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;

            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

            server_name purple.com;

            location ~* ^/(.*)$ {        

                            proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;

            }

}
server {
            listen 80;

            server_name purple.com

            return 301 https://purple.com $request_uri;

}
`
